# asp.net web api : bind request body values to the model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In web API I have situation from client the request body is like below

```
{ "device-id":100101,"device-name": "Samsung 001"}


my model class
public class DeviceDesc
{
    public string device_id {get;set;}
    public string device_name {get;set;}
}

So the values are not binding to the properties.  In c# we cannot declare         properties with " - " symbol.  So how I can do this in web api.  the request body cannot be changed bcoz the JSON is generated by some third-party app.  Please, any solution for this.
```

Thanks
Saroj

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="JSON_NAME"]` in JSON.NET. For example:

```
public class DeviceDesc
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="device-id"]
    public string device_id {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="device-name"]
    public string device_name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: No prob! Good luck